# Jquery click event repeats itself... sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm having a weird (annoying) issue with a small jquery complement I'm coding. It is meant to control a small tabbed nav for content on a page, it's not meant to be a big deal. It currently has 3 buttons (tabs) and the system is meant to fade out the current tab and content and change to the new one when you click on any of the tabs.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7Trd/)

The HTML goes as follows:

```
            <div class="fixed-wing-nav-cont">
                <div class="fixed-wing-nav">
                    <div class="fixed-wing-nav-item" id="wing-nav-1">Features</div>
                    <div class="fixed-wing-nav-item"  id="wing-nav-2">Benefits</div>
                    <div class="fixed-wing-nav-item active"  id="wing-nav-3">Screenshots</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fixed-wing-tab-cont">
                <div id="fixed-wing-tab-1">
                    Features Tab
                </div>
                <div id="fixed-wing-tab-2">
                    Benefits Tab
                </div>
                <div id="fixed-wing-tab-3" class="active">
                    <img src="images/screens.png" alt="screens" /> <a href="#" class="red">VIEW ALL</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

And the CSS tied to it, just in case it might be important, is the following:

```
.fixed-wing-nav-cont{
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #747474;
    margin:20px 0;
}

.fixed-wing-nav{
    display:table;
    border-spacing:5px 0;
    border-collapse:separate;
    margin-left:-5px;
}

.fixed-wing-nav-item{
    margin-right:40px;
    height:40px;
    color:#1c5fa9;
    font-size:16px;
    border-left:1px solid #1c5fa9;
    border-top:1px solid #1c5fa9;
    border-right:1px solid #1c5fa9;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 10px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.fixed-wing-nav-item.active{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#1c5fa9;
}

.fixed-wing-tab-cont{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}

.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
}

.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div.active{
    display:block;
}

.fixed-wing-tab-cont img{
    border:none;
}
```

The Jquery complement is a very simple one  - I know there are more elegant ways to do it, but I chose to go for what's meant to be faster to code, and simpler overall:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#wing-nav-1').click(function(){
    $('div.fixed-wing-nav-item').removeClass("active",function(){
        $('#wing-nav-1').addClass("active");
    });
    $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').removeClass("active");
    $('.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('#fixed-wing-tab-1').fadeIn("fast");
    });
});

$('#wing-nav-2').click(function(){
    $('div.fixed-wing-nav-item').removeClass("active",function(){
        $('#wing-nav-2').addClass("active");
    });
    $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').removeClass("active");
    $('.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('#fixed-wing-tab-2').fadeIn("fast");
    });
});

$('#wing-nav-3').click(function(){
    $('div.fixed-wing-nav-item').removeClass("active",function(){
        $('#wing-nav-3').addClass("active");
    });
    $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').removeClass("active");
    $('.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').fadeIn("fast");
    });
});

</script>
```

I'm loading Jquery 1.9 straight from the jquery site. Now, the issue I'm having is this: The page opens with the third tab loaded, no problems. If I click to go to the first tab, it works perfectly: The third tab fades out, the first one fades in and the "active" state from the tab button is moved from the third to the first one. If I then choose to go to the second tab it also works perfectly. However, if I try to go from any tab to the third one or from the third to the second it plays the animation twice, which makes no sense whatsoever: All three tabs are running the same code. I've been looking at the code over and over for an hour and I can't see why this is happening - Why does the first tab work perfectly, but the third one have such issues? I've tried removing the "active" state from all items in the HTML (thus making the tab/content start empty) and the issue still happens.

Can anyone help me here? This just doesn't make any sense to me :\

Comment: You should always call `.stop(true, true)` before animating an element to ensure that any previous queued animations are finished. [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: For each click you remove class active from tab-3. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, it is ok. It isn't necessary, I put it there as a safety measure since the active class for content was meant to show it. When jQuery animates, it doesn't care about the "active" part, since jquery animations instead add inline css that takes precedence over whatever the active class says.

Also, the system works the same without that line, so feel free to ignore it - I added said line after it started bugging out, in hopes it might help, but it didn't :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were fading out all of your DIVs under the class .fixed-wing-tab-cont.  So the content loading twice was really just the content being faded out and fading back in.  You can exclude the DIV with the active class using the CSS 'not' selector in jQuery.  Change

```
$('#wing-nav-3').click(function(){
    $('div.fixed-wing-nav-item').removeClass("active",function(){
        $('#wing-nav-3').addClass("active");
    });
    $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').removeClass("active");
    $('.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

to

```
$('#wing-nav-3').click(function(){
    $('div.fixed-wing-nav-item').removeClass("active");
    $('#wing-nav-3').addClass("active");
    $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').removeClass("active");
    $('.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div:not(.active)').fadeOut("fast");
    $('#fixed-wing-tab-3').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

There is really no need for you to use callback functions in this instance.  In fact, the removeClass method has no callback ability.  You might have noticed that your active tab class wasn't being applied to the tabs you clicked on because of this.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7Trd/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this did it!

Although to streamline it a bit I ended up removing the "active" class from the content div, instead putting some inline css to make it show, but that works fine without repeating. I'm still wondering why the error didn't affect the first div or when I moved between first and second div, though.

EDIT: By the way, the active class was actually being properly applied to the tab links, even if the function definition says it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You remove the 'active' class from the fixed-wing-nav-item divs correctly, but always remove the 'active' class from '#fixed-wing-tab-3', regardless of which of the tabs is active.  If you removed the 'active' class from '.fixed-wing-tab-cont>div' and then add the 'active' class to the fixed-wing-tab you fadeIn it should work.

Comment: The remove there is only because it's the only tab using active - the other tabs are just being animated using fadein/out, not using the 'active' class. The way jQuery manages animations is, it adds inline css to the item being faded in or out so to ensure its effects will take precedence over any css that might be applied, so in truth the removeClass I have there is redundant. I put it after the system started bugging out, and if you test the code without it you'll see it still does the same :\